# Can't log in to Stack Overflow with ClaimID

Tags: support, login

As of yesterday, my ClaimID credentials no longer work on Stack Overflow. I get the following error this morning:

```
Unable to log in with your OpenID provider:

Error occurred while sending a direct message or getting the response.
```

It was a somewhat different second message yesterday:

```
No OpenID endpoint found.
```

My ID is clearly good, since I got logged in here. Is it me, or them?

EDIT:

Forgot to mention, it happens with either IE or Firefox.

EDIT 2:

I can now log in again via ClaimID. I didn't do anything, it just started working again. Sigh.

Comment: We don't allow clams to join, I'm afraid.

Comment: It happens to me too, with ClaimID and ClickPass. I reset my browser to test a site, and I had to create a Stack Exchange account to log in, or I would not be able to write this comment.

Comment: note that ClaimID is basically defunct, they haven't supported new user signups for over a year now. So I recommend adding some other more reliable identity provider -- remember you can have as many of these in your "wallet" as you like -- such as Stack Exchange, Google, Facebook, etc.