# ClaimId: Login failure

Tags: support, login

I'm unable to log in with my claim id. It complains that the site maybe a fake www.clamid.com vs openid.claimid.com. I'm not sure which end (SO or claim) is broken but can you please advise.

It might even be a security certificate issue on claimid.com as https: is blocked. I note they seem to have recently updated their interface.

[image]

Says cert error in image but whether that means Stack Overflow is now referencing an obsolete endpoint or claim is in error I'm unsure... they don't respond.

Comment: I'm getting this too, on multiple sites. Instead of getting directed to the claimID "login and trust" page, I just get directed to the front page...

Comment: I have this too, fortunately I had cached credentials on SF, so I created new login on stackexchange and added it to on my SF user page.

Comment: Of course, without being able to login, this question is missing a crapload of up-votes

Comment: Indeed, I had to create an account just to vote and comment on this issue

Comment: Don't have enough reputation to vote, that's ironic ;o)

Answer (score 3):

Claimid seems to be broken for me, too. If you have cached credentials on any SE site (as Hubert Kario advises), go to your profile → *my logins* → *add more logins ...* and create a new SE login. This will also create a new OpenID through the SE network.

**Update**, 2012-11-27: Got a note from Terrell Russell at ClaimID. He said the issue was fixed, and indeed it is now. But do try to get as many openids as you can as backup.

Comment: and if there are no cached credentials?

Comment: indeed, what to do in this case?

Answer (score 2):

I sent a mail to claimid.com support, and will wait a couple of days for an answer.

After that, I'll try to regain my account throuth StackExchange support, I guess.

**Edit:** Sent a request through the defunct openID provider workflow:

https://stackoverflow.com/help/defunct

Everything should be sorted out shortly.

**Edit2:** See Jeff Atwood's comment [there](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117437/cant-log-in-to-stack-overflow-with-claimid?rq=1), which claims that claimID isn't doing well. Which may or may not explain why there are login and SSL issues with these guys

Comment: well, no news from ClaimID support...

Comment: I too sent them an email when the problem arose as per some days prior to the date of this  questions posting. Today they responded that the problem is resolved. I would recommend now logging in if poss and adding more openids as backups to your account. For me, Googleid is the most trusted due to their scale.